# edit vars in an extern JS File

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a html file and a JS file.
In the JS file are vars:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    fps: 30,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/logo_bg.png", id:"logo_bg"}
    ]
};
....
```

Now, you see the source path of an image. -> images/logo_bg.png

How do I change the path in my html file?

```
<head>
<script src="test.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}
function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.test();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
```

The idea to handle it with "getElementById" doesn't work yet...

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can't edit it manually on file itself? or do you not have control over the file?

Comment: nope. thats not the idea. i want handle this dynamiclly

Comment: @MatthiasStähle I think that you don't need the [flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag, I removed it.

Comment: Well that code is generated with flash. so I think i need it. But thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

via DOM manipulation.

```
$('#yourImage').attr("src", "your/new/path");
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("yourImage").setAttribute("src", "your/new/path");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: <body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>

<script>
document.getElementById("logo_bg").setAttribute("src", "images/logo_bg_2.png");
</script>

Comment: is there an error in your console? did you check if the attribute is set to the element?

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
test.html
Line 48

Comment: plz post your html code - update your question to do so